# In WordPress, I need to italicize a certain phrase in each page's content

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I have a WordPress site that I'm working on, which has a large section of the site that describes plant species.  Each plant name begins with "R.", and is followed by the species name.  For example, one instance is "R. adenogynum."  **All of these names must be italicized**.

There are many instances of this, and to do it by hand would be very time-consuming.  I'm trying to write a plugin that will check/italicize all the words in $content, each time "the_content" is run.  In other words, I'm using an

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'italicize' )

function italicize($content) {
...
```

function to do this.

I've tried to use the explode method like so:

```
$words = explode( ' ', $content );
```

and then checking each word in the $words array, but the problem is that whitespace and HTML tags also are part of $content, and this jumbles everything.  Plus I would have to use implode to put everything back together, which is a bit messy as well.

So how can I edit these plant names successfully with a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this plugin:
http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/search-regex/

It allows you to do a regex search and search/replace for your phrase.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job best suited to [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Your function would look something like this:

```
function italicize_plant_names ($content) {  
    $content = preg_replace('(R\.\s+\w+)', '<em>$0</em>', $content);
    return content;
}
```

[Demo of the php code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/750439ca501628dc6cab0361530c9d000d3f07a3), and [Regular Expression tester](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions syntax.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function($content) {
    return preg_replace("/(R\. [a-z]+)/", "<i>$1</i>", $content);   
});
```

This will match any phrase that begins with "R." followed by a space, followed by an all lowercase word and replace it with an italicized version of that word.

Comment: Note that you need to be running PHP > 5.3 to use anonymous functions.